# Difference in assignment/initialization of shared pointer

Tags: c++11

We can initialize a shared_pointer in three ways.

```
1. shared_ptr<int>p(new int(8));
2. shared_ptr<int>p=shared_ptr<int>(8);
3. shared_ptr<int>p=make_shared<int>(8);
```

We know 3rd statement has an advantage over 1st statement, in terms of single operation initialization and exception handling support.

Is there any difference between 1st and 2nd statements according to exception thrown, performance etc..

Comment: Assuming 2. was meant to use `new int(8)`, C++17 guarantees that 1. and 2. must be the same

Comment: It also has been allowed and common for compilers to make 1. and 2. the same since C++98

Answer (score 0):

The second way of initialization does not work.
It has to be:

`shared_ptr<int> p2 = shared_ptr<int>(new int(8));`

Apart from that, there is no difference between 1 and 2 as the same constructor is used for both.

Comment: User::KABoissonneault  already suggested this in the comments.